# How to use move_base with the DWA planner as the local planner in kinetic

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa, dwa-local-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am really confused as how to use the DWA for local planning with move_base.
It seems that dwa is now a bool parameter of the base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS. But then how to access the dw_local_planner parameters, such as forward_point_distance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235266/how-to-use-move_base-with-the-dwa-planner-as-the-local-planner-in-kinetic/) by [doisyg](https://answers.ros.org/users/25266/doisyg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2016-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved!
I was getting errors while starting move_base with DWA in a classical way because i forgot to install the proper package:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-dwa-local-planner
```

Now everything is working well.

For reference i set the local planner as DWA by adding this line to my move_base.launch file:

```
<param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/>
```

I can then set the params with a *.yaml file:

```
DWAPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.4
  min_vel_x: 0.1

  max_trans_vel: 0.4
  min_trans_vel: 0.1
  
  etc....
```

Sorry for shooting to fast. But to be fair the documentation of the navigation stack is not very clear on this point...

---

Originally posted by [doisyg](https://answers.ros.org/users/25266/doisyg/) with karma: 141 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-06**:
Thank you for pointing this out. I've been wondering the same thing myself. This answer should be marked as the correct one.